# Page breaking issue with colored environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, page-breaking

I have the following problem.
In the preamble I have the following:

```
\newcounter{problem}[chapter]\setcounter{problem}{0}
\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{problem}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{problem}

\ifstrempty{#1}%
% if condition (without title)
{\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!0]
        {\strut Problem~\theproblem};}
    }%
% else condition (with title)
}{\mdfsetup{%
    frametitle={%
       \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!0]
        {\strut Problem~\theproblem:~#1};}%
    }%
}%
% Both conditions
\mdfsetup{%
    innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=red!50,%
    linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax%
}

\begin{mdframed}[]\relax}{%
\end{mdframed}}}}
```

Then in the document I write:

```
\begin{problem}[Name]
    Text
\end{problem}
```

My pdf file breaks the page between [Name] and Text as in the pictures (they are taken from different pages). It also misses the first letter (unless I put {} after \begin{problem}), but this does not bother me a lot.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix the page breaking issue?

Comment: Your environment has two arguments, one optional and one mandatory. So you should use it as `\begin{problem}[Optional]{Mandatory}`. Beside this: use tcolorbox instead of mdframed for this - tcolorbox is much better and much more reliable.

Comment: If I change to tcolorbox, it takes the title away. If I write as you proposed \begin{problem}[Optional]{Mandatory} it still does the page breaking...

Comment: tcolorbox has a quite good documentation.

Comment: It does. What I really want for the title is what I have on the picture -- there is a rectangle around the text and it does not go through the "Problem 1.1: Name" thing. As far I have understood from tcolorbox package it does not allow to do that, giving the boxes for full environments instead, which is the reason why I use mdframed.

Comment: Everything you do with mdframed can also be done with tcolorbox.

Comment: It is not MWE. Please post a MWE!